# Align two RadioListTile tiles to center of the Column

Tags: flutter

I have added two `RadioListTiles` to One column. I want to center them to the center of the screen. 
here is the code : 
child:

```
body: Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      height: double.infinity,
      color: Color.fromRGBO(20, 124, 148, 1),
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            width: 180,
            child: Column(
              //mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                RadioListTile(
                  value: 0,
                  title: Text("Surah"),
                  groupValue: groupValue,
                  onChanged: (v) {
                    setState(() {
                      groupValue = v;
                    });
                  },
                  activeColor: Colors.white,
                ),
                RadioListTile(
                  value: 1,
                  title: Text("Identicals"),
                  groupValue: groupValue,
                  onChanged: (v) {
                    setState(() {
                      groupValue = v;
                    });
                  },
                  activeColor: Colors.white,
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          CustomBottomSheet(),
        ],
      ),
    )
```

CustomBottomSheet() is a Container, it will hold a listView , when the grey toggle button is pressed , it will conver the entire screen !

Here are the screenshots :

[screenShot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lw1kt.jpg)
[screenShot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VCNi.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why `RadioListTile` is not aligning itself to the center is that it takes the entire width of the screen.
To get around this limitation, we can wrap the `Column` in a parent `Container` with the fixed width so that the `RadioListTile` will inherit its width, then we can easily center the Container with `Center` widget and the children of `Column` with `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,`.

Here is the example:

```
void main() {
  runApp(RadioTileCenter());
}

class RadioTileCenter extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RadioTileCenterState createState() => _RadioTileCenterState();
}

class _RadioTileCenterState extends State<RadioTileCenter> {
  int groupValue = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Center RadioTile")),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
            width: 200,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                RadioListTile(
                  value: 0,
                  groupValue: groupValue,
                  title: Text(
                    "Surah",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green),
                  ),
                  onChanged: (v) {
                    setState(() {
                      groupValue = v;
                    });
                  },
                  activeColor: Colors.green,
                ),
                RadioListTile(
                  value: 1,
                  groupValue: groupValue,
                  title: Text(
                    "Identicals",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green),
                  ),
                  onChanged: (v) {
                    setState(() {
                      groupValue = v;
                    });
                  },
                  activeColor: Colors.green,
                )
              ],
            )),
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Updated Code with bottomsheet:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class RadioTileCenter extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RadioTileCenterState createState() => _RadioTileCenterState();
}

class _RadioTileCenterState extends State<RadioTileCenter> {
  int groupValue = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Builder(
      builder: (context) => Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Center RadioTile")),
        body: Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          height: double.infinity,
          color: Color.fromRGBO(20, 124, 148, 1),
          child: Center(
            child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  width: 180,
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      RadioListTile(
                        value: 0,
                        title: Text("Surah"),
                        groupValue: groupValue,
                        onChanged: (v) {
                          setState(() {
                            groupValue = v;
                          });
                        },
                        activeColor: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      RadioListTile(
                        value: 1,
                        title: Text("Identicals"),
                        groupValue: groupValue,
                        onChanged: (v) {
                          setState(() {
                            groupValue = v;
                          });
                        },
                        activeColor: Colors.white,
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                // CustomBottomSheet(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            _settingModalBottomSheet(context);
          },
          child: new Icon(Icons.add),
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
}

void _settingModalBottomSheet(context) {
  showModalBottomSheet(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext bc) {
        print("hi");
        return Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
              topRight: Radius.circular(20),
            ),
          ),
          child: new Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              new ListTile(
                  leading: new Icon(Icons.music_note),
                  title: new Text('Music'),
                  onTap: () => {}),
              new ListTile(
                leading: new Icon(Icons.videocam),
                title: new Text('Video'),
                onTap: () => {},
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      });
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Agree.
I set to 200 as it's big enough to wrap both Radio Tiles perfectly producing the desired result.

Comment: Thanks but how can i center them without using Center widget ? Actually I have a Stack(). where the RadioTiles will appear at the top and a CustomBottom Sheet will cover them when any radio button is pressed !

Comment: The Column is the child of Stack? Can you update the code for more clarity?

Comment: What if the text is long that you can't wrap inside 200, this is a very narrow solution.

Comment: Eminent Overflow error. This solution was specific to the above question. I am also curious about how to calculate the overall width of the tile so that width can be set dynamically, any suggestions?

Comment: #ketanRamteke i have updated the code, do check , thankyou !!

Comment: wrap Stack in Center widget and give Column mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,

Comment: Wrapping the container of RadioListTile in Center widget worked for me, Thanks Ketan